# How to Combine FFT Overlap Results?

Tags: fft, window-functions, window

We currently have C/C++ FFT code with Hann Window function support. For a large data (over 10,000) we want to split this into 1024 samples with 50% overlap. For each 1024 sample, we window and fft.

What is the recommended way to combine all the results from these smaller overlapping results to obtain a presentable results for the over 10,000 data?

**Update**: For the poor explanation.
The process is best illustrated by the following links

https://spectraplus.com/DT_help/overlap_percentage.htm

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LlyH6YciDhw

Comment: i wasn't the one to down-arrow you, but could you be more specific about what is is that you *have* done or *can* do, and then what it is that you're missing?  maybe a little code or pseudo-code would be illustrative.

Comment: Why the overlap? Is the signal you expect a transient one? Overlap is usually done for better IFFT.

Comment: I have added links to illustrate the process. My thought is to combine the non-overlapping FFT output for the final result, but could not find any source of information to confirm that approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your intent is, but the organization of the computation can be done using straightforward [overlap-and-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method) or [overlap-and-save](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93save_method) methods.

If you're attempting to look at data statistics in the frequency domain, a good starting might be to look at [Welch's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_method) and its descendents.

Comment: Thanks, I found out it falls under **FFT Averaging** and looking into that right now.